# program evaluating if clause incorrectly

Tags: error

As the title says i'm having a problem with an if clause evaluating incorrectly in one particular function

```
uint16_t    getSleepTime()
{
    volatile uint8_t flag = EEPROM.read(3);

    uint8_t high    = EEPROM.read(0);
    uint8_t low     = EEPROM.read(1);

    if(flag != 0xaa);
    {
        Serial.println(flag);
        Serial.println("ERROR: SLEEP TIME NOT DEFINED, CANNOT CONTINUE.");
        while(true)
        {
            digitalWrite(PIN_LED, true);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite(PIN_LED, false);
            delay(250);
            wdt_reset();
        }
    }

    return word(high, low);
}
```

the result is that the if function evaluates as true always
my first thought was, ok the eeprom wasn't written properly, hence i added the println, the returned value was 170 == 0xaa
then i thought well maybe the flag variable is optimized out, hence the volatile
and then, well maybe its a type comparison issue so i also defined a const uint8_t flagv with value 0xaa
same results in every case

```
13:21:00.991 -> 170
13:21:00.991 -> ERROR: SLEEP TIME NOT DEFINED, CANNOT CONTINUE.
and the corresponding blink
```

the thing is that being such a trivial code i'm out of ideas right now, as anyone here experienced something like this?

Comment: when debugging, put `Serial.println(flag);` before the `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put a `;` after an if:

```
if(flag != 0xaa);
```

is the same as

```
if(flag != 0xaa)
{
}
```

Meaning that the code after the `if` statement is always executed.

Comment: ouch, dumb mistake

Comment: No problem, however, I also have to vote for closing, since it's not related to Arduino.